# Opening a folder with ReferenceFileDocument in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to allow users to pick folders using the DocumentGroup context in SwiftUI, having defined a SourceFolderDocument class inheriting from ReferenceFileDocument.

However, when launching the app, only elements conforming to .sourceCode are pickable in the file picker. What would be the correct way to pick folders to open in SwiftUI?

Thank you in advance!

Here is the class in question:

```swift
    final class SourceFolderDocument: ReferenceFileDocument{
    static var readableContentTypes: [UTType] {[.folder, .sourceCode, .directory]}
    
    init(configuration: ReadConfiguration) throws {
        var documents : [SourceFile] = []
        if(configuration.file.isDirectory){
            guard let wrappers = configuration.file.fileWrappers
            else{
                throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
            }
            var documents : [SourceFile] = []
            for document in wrappers {
                if let fileContents = document.value.regularFileContents{
                    documents.append(SourceFile(name: document.key, contents: String(data: fileContents, encoding: .utf8)!, fileUTType: .sourceCode))
                }
            }
        }else{
            guard let data = configuration.file.regularFileContents
            else{
                throw CocoaError(.fileReadCorruptFile)
            }
            documents.append(SourceFile(name: configuration.file.filename ?? "blank", contents: String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "", fileUTType: .sourceCode))
        }
        self.sourceFolder = SourceFolder(name: configuration.file.filename!, documents: documents)
    }
    
    func snapshot(contentType: UTType) throws -> SourceFolder {
        sourceFolder
    }
    
    func fileWrapper(snapshot: SourceFolder, configuration: WriteConfiguration) throws -> FileWrapper {
        var fileWrappers: [String : FileWrapper] = [:]
        for document in snapshot.documents {
            fileWrappers[document.name] = FileWrapper(regularFileWithContents: document.contents.data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
        let fileWrapper = FileWrapper(directoryWithFileWrappers: fileWrappers)
        return fileWrapper
    }
    
    init(){
        sourceFolder = .defaultFolder
    }
    
    typealias Snapshot = SourceFolder
    
    @Published var sourceFolder : SourceFolder
}
```

Comment: Did you have any luck solving this issue? I've just bumped into this issue myself and struggling to find an answer...

Answer (score -1):

Since the menu is only using NSOpenPanel, I was about to suggest to create a small function:

```
fileprivate func openPanel()  {
    let panel = NSOpenPanel()
    panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    panel.canChooseDirectories = true
    if panel.runModal() == .OK,
       let url = panel.url {
        Task {
            try? await openDocument(at: url)
        }
    }
}
```

And then append to your view the new "Open Folder" menu:

```
.commandsReplaced {
    CommandGroup(after: .newItem) {
        Section {
            Button("Open Folders") {
                openPanel()
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This would be creating (or replacing) the existing menus and it should also be possible to replace the "Open" menu.